# FullCalendar Show different information on dayClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I have a calendar that shows different information on the month view and day view. I'd like to be able to allow the user to click into a day, then have the day show the specifics of each event. This is what I currently have below.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
            height: 750,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today ',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month'
            },
            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

            },
            displayEventTime: false,
            events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'WebServices/CalendarAtAGlanceWebService.asmx/GetCalendarSessions',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ date: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate') }),
                    async: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (doc) {
                        var events = [];
                        $(doc.d).each(function () {
                            events.push({
                                title: $(this).attr('EventName'),
                                start: $(this).attr('StartDate'), // will be parsed
                                description: $(this).attr("EventDescription")
                            });
                        });
                        callback(events);
                    }
                });
            },
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.description);
            }
        });
```

[Full Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kinZw.png) This is what the image looks like on the month view.

Answer (score 0):

Make your dayClick function the following:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view)
{
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', agendaDay);
}
```

This will change the view to the day view of the clicked date when the user clicks on a day in month view. Then you just need to change your eventRender 
logic to only display the description when in day view:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) 
{
    if($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name == "agendaDay")
    {
        element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.description);
    }
}
```

This will make the description only appear for the events in day view. This means that you will see titles only in month view, and clicking on a day will show a view of the day's events with more detail.